# AWS S3 - Display image in HTML

Tags: html, image, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-s3

I can't seem to figure out why my image which lives in AWS is not displaying in my HTML.  I'ts simply displaying a white image with the small icon in the top right noting there is no image found (And no alt attribute).

If this is the URL to the image:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mng-moment/test/PA/40.0103647%2C-75.2625353_1492304397972.jpg

Then shouldn't the `img src` be

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mng-moment/test/PA/40.0103647,-75.2625353_1492304397972.jpg

I have also tried to match the URL exactly.  I tried to print out in the HTML exactly what is in the img src.  I tried to take out the extension along with other miscellaneous things.

I have done some research on this and it seems like I'm doing it correctly, although clearly i'm not.  Any idea what is wrong here?

Thanks for any and all help.

EDIT:

This is the code where I create the object to upload:

```
        var blob = new Blob([dataURItoBlob(picture)], {type: 'image/jpg'});
        var file = new File([blob], moment.location);
        return core.upload(moment.key, moment);
```

Comment: I just tried your second link. The file downloads, but the contents is not a JPG image.

Comment: Oh thats interesting.  I didn't know you can download it from the link.  When I click on it I get a noSuchKey error.

Comment: Wait, nevermind I know why.  I was playing around with it and I deleted the file.

Comment: Your object key contains ',' which is not under safe characters list (Check the following link). Can you upload a file with a simple name and check whether its accessible? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know there was a safe character list.  I replaced the comma with a '_' however, I still can't display it.

Comment: Apparently when I try to open it, it's not a jpg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  It was this thing:

```
    var blob = new Blob([dataURItoBlob(picture)], {type: 'image/jpg'});
    var file = new File([blob], moment.location);
    return core.upload(moment.key, moment);
```

I was foolishly not passing in the file into my upload function even though I went through the trouble of creating it.  It must've been a refactoring mistake I made.